# Loading Hbase table with Pig. Float gives FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I've got a HBase table that is loaded via the HBase Java api like so:

```
put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HBaseConnection.FAMILY_NAME), Bytes.toBytes("value"), Bytes.toBytes(value));
```

(Where the variable `value` is a normal java float.)

I proceed to load this with Pig as follows:

```
raw = LOAD 'hbase://tableName' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('family:value', '-loadKey true -limit 5') AS (id:chararray, value:float);
```

However when I dump this with:

```
dump raw;
```

I get:

```
[main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 5 time(s).
```

for each float value. The ID's are printed fine.

Im running:

- Apache Hadoop 0.20.2.05
- Pig 0.9.2
- Hbase 0.92.0

**My question: Why cant pig handle theses float values? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Try it without the `AS (id:chararray, value:float)` part. What does it dump? Try converting value to a String before calling Bytes.toBytes on it, just to know what the problem is.

Comment: I removed the "as" clause as you suggested but all I get is odd looking Udf-8 characters (since the data is binary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you have to add a caster. Like so:

```
USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('family:value', '-loadKey true -limit 5 -caster HBaseBinaryConverter')
```

Comment: Did limit work for you as intended? I gave this command **(field = LOAD 'hbase://documents' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('info:collection', '-loadKey true -limit 5 -caster HBaseBinaryConverter') as (id:chararray, field:chararray );)** and then used 'dump field'. After the mapreduce hbase shows 260 records loaded and dumped instead of 5. I do not understand why

Answer (score 0):

Please try by following way:

```
test = load '/user/training/user' using PigStorage(',') 
  as (user_id, name, age:int, country, gender);
```

As default delimiter for loading is **tab**.