# PIG - HBASE - Casting values

Tags: hadoop, casting, hbase, apache-pig

I'm using PIG to process rows in an HBase table.  The values in the HBase table are stored as bytearrays.

I can't figure out if I have to write a UDF that casts bytearrays to various types, or if pig does that automatically.

I have the following script:

```
raw = LOAD 'hbase://TABLE' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('CF:I') AS (product_id:bytearray);
ids = FOREACH raw GENERATE (int)product_id;
dump ids;
```

I get a list of parenthesis `'()'`.

According to the [docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#cast), it should work.  I checked the value in hbase shell they're all  `value=\x00\x00\x00\x02`

How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to add the following option to get it to cast...

```
LOAD 'hbase://TABLE' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('CF:I','-caster HBaseBinaryConverter') AS (product_id:bytearray);
```

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480788/loading-hbase-table-with-pig-float-gives-field-discarded-type-conversion-failed).

Answer (score 0):

If you have non-text values in the columns, you need to specify the -caster option with HBaseBinaryConverter(default is Utf8StorageConverter) and map them to respective types so that PIG will cast them properly before serializing them in text.

```
a = load 'hbase://TESTTABLE_1' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('TESTCOLUMN_A TESTCOLUMN_B TESTCOLUMN_C ','-loadKey -caster HBaseBinaryConverter') as (rowKey:chararray,col_a:int, col_b:double, col_c:chararray);
```